# How do I disable the mousewheel zoom in Here Maps JavaScript API v3?

Tags: here-api

The code to disable mousewheel zoom on Here Maps JS API v2 was this:

```
map.removeComponent(map.getComponentById("zoom.MouseWheel"));
```

But that is an undefined function in v3 of the API. What is the best way to disable mousewheel zoom in the latest API?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
behavior.disable(H.mapevents.Behavior.WHEELZOOM);
```

Comment: Where is "behavior" located?

Comment: You create a behaviour (https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.22.1/api_reference/H.mapevents.Behavior.html) yourself. An example can be found in the developers guide (https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.22.1/dev_guide/topics/map-events.html).